# Как мне вырезать путь файла?

Tags: php, laravel

***строчка в контроллере***

```
$user->spravka035 =$request =$target_file_name.'.'.$type ;
```

> выводит в БД ([image: введите сюда описание изображения])
>
> а мне нужно только ([image: введите сюда описание изображения])

Comment: basename($request)

Answer (score 1):

```
$user->spravka035 =basename($request=$target_file_name.'.'.$type );
```